# Find the count of duplicate records in talend and java

Tags: java, postgresql, count, duplicates, talend

I have a table in postgresql which has duplicate numbers in a column. I am using Tpostgresqlinput and a query in this as :

```
select number , count(1) from abc.xyz having count(1)>1 group by number
```

After this component, I am using tFlowToIterate and then  Tjavaflex. In tJavaflex , I am using

Startcode as :

```
int count = 0; count++;
```

Maincode as :

```
if (count>1) 
("row1.serial_number",row1.serial_number)
    System.out.println(row1.serial_number);
else
    System.out.println("Duplicates are not found");
```

But I am getting the output with the else part as Duplicates are not found.

**How do I find the count and name of those serial numbers if it is more than 0 ?**

Ideally , the serial numbers should be unique but then there are duplicate serial numbers in the data.So I want to find the duplicate serial number and its count only if it is greater than 1 as an output.
Expected output should be : if there are duplicates ie if the count of serial number is more than 1 then it should send a mail notification to the user that those serial numbers have the count more than 1 ie the serial number and the count no.

Comment: can you tell after your tpostgressqlinput what is the output you want ..final output..may be there is easier way to do this without using tflowtoiterate and tjavaflex...can you give an example of your input and your expected output..like  say input is ....and expected output is .......

Comment: expected output should be : if there are duplicates ie if the count of serial number is more than 1 then it should send a mail notification to the user that those serial numbers have the count more than 1 ie the serial number and its count. Ideally , the serial numbers should be unique but then there are duplicate serial numbers in the data.So I want to find the duplicate serial number and its count only if it is greater than 1.

Comment: ok. then all you need to do is after you tpostgressqlinput you should have tMap and in tMap you create a output group based on count value. if its >1 then data gets into this group. Further you can write this data into a csv file or excel or text file. Next when all such records are written, you can send an email with this list as attachment or even read this file and append this data into email text.   TpostgresSqlInput-->tMap(outputgroup where count(*)>1)--->tFileInputDelimited....Then OnSubJobOK of this you can read this csv and send email as text or send email with attachment

Comment: You have to aggregate, and filter the output of the aggregate. There are components for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your start code, you init count as 0 and increment by one, which leads to count = 1. This value never changes and therefore you always get the else part of your if.

What you actually want to do is use the count from your input. To accomplish this, use a tJavaRow with:

```
if(input_row.count > 1)
  System.out.println(input_row.serial_number);
else
  System.out.println("Duplicates are not found");
```